# A different ring on the integers such that addition and multiplication are polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

One can define rings other than the standard one on the set of integers so that both of the operations are polynomials, for example $(\mathbb Z, +', \times')$ with $a+'b=(a+1)+(b+1)-1$ and $a\times'b=(a+1)(b+1)-1$. I think I saw a less silly example a few years ago. However both examples turn out to be isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z, +, \times)$. Is there such a ring that isn't isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z, +, \times)$?

The question is loosely motivated by computing. Computation models are often defined to have the addition and multiplication operations as basic operations. Some techniques use fields (in this case I was thinking about polynomial/rolling hashes) but can run into issues with the standard integers, so it would be nice to have a ring that can be easily "implemented" with integers.

Comment: Sure; find any ring $R$ of cardinality $\aleph_0$ that is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, let $\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}\to R$ be a bijection, and define the structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ by transport of structure, $a+'b = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a)+\phi(b))$ and $a\times'b = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a)\times\phi(b))$.

Comment: @arturomagidin Does that guarantee that $a+'b$ and $a\times'b$ are polynomials in $a,b$?

Comment: Not by itself, no. But I think you could do it if you let $R$ have underlying set $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with a "polynomial" operation... thought it might take some checking.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin -- I thought about this too, but I'm not sure if it works out. As far as I know it's [open](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117390/polynomial-bijection-from-zxz-to-z) whether there are polynomial bijections from $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a commutative ring structure on $\mathbb Z$ as follows: $a+'b=p(a,b)$ and $a\times'b=q(a,b)$, where $p(X,Y),q(X,Y)\in\mathbb Z[X,Y]$. Note that since $p$ and $q$ are symmetric, we have that $p,q\in \mathbb Z[X+Y,XY]$.

For each $a\in\mathbb Z$ we must have $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z:x\mapsto x+'a=p(x,a)$ is bijective, hence $p(X,a)$ must be a degree-$1$ polynomial of $X$. Thus $p(X,Y)$ must be of the form $\alpha+\beta(X+Y)+\gamma XY$ for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb Z$. Now we need the map $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z:x\mapsto x+'a=\alpha+\beta a+(\beta+\gamma a)x$ to be bijectice for each $a\in\mathbb Z$, so that $\gamma=0$ and $\beta=\pm1$. However, if $\beta=-1$ we must have that

$$p(p(X,Y),Z)=p(\alpha-X-Y,Z)=X+Y-Z$$

is symmetric with respect to permutation of $X,Y,Z$, which is clearly not true. Thus we conclude that $\beta=1$ and $p(X,Y)=\alpha+X+Y$. Thus, $0'=-\alpha$, and by shifting everything by $\alpha$ (that is, applying the bijection $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z:x\mapsto x+\alpha$) we may simply assume $\alpha=0$.

Now, $q$ must be a polynomial such that $q(X+Y,Z)=q(X,Z)+q(Y,Z)$, hence it must be of the form $q(X,Y)=f(X)Y$ for some polynomial $f(X)\in\mathbb Z[X]$. Since $q$ must be symmetric, it must be the case that $f(X)=aX$ for $a\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. The existence of a multiplicative unit tells us that $a=\pm1$. Either way, by considering the isomorphism $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z:x\to ax$ we may assume $a=1$, so that $(\mathbb Z,+',\times')\cong(\mathbb Z,+,\times)$.

**P.S.**

We may arrive at the same conclusion *without* assuming commutativity, since distributivity on the left tells us that $q(X,Y)$ is of the form $Xg(Y)$ for some $g(Y)\in\mathbb Z[Y]$.